# problem with the truffle develop command

Tags: truffle

I am trying to use the "truffle develop" command but it does not work.
I get this error message below. It seems to say there is a problem in the truffle-config file but there is no error.

Do you have any idea about solving this problem?

[image: Problem with truffle develop]

Here is the content of the truffle-config.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');

const secrets = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('.secrets-example').toString().trim()
);

module.exports = {
    networks: {
        ropsten: {
            provider: () =>
            new HDWalletProvider(
                secrets.seed,
                `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${secrets.projectID}`
            ),
            network_id: 3
        }
    }
};
```

And here is the content of the migration file:

```
const Crud = artifacts.require("Crud");

module.exports = function(deployer) {

  deployer.deploy(Crud);
};
```

Thank you in advance

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with a string appearing in JSON, maybe in your config file at `start/truffle-config.js`? Post that and migrations file and maybe we will be able to help more (as code not as pictures).

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I copy paste the content of the truffle-config.js file and of the migration file in the original message.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for that @Pierre . I believe the issue is with this line:

const secrets = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync('.secrets-example').toString().trim() );

Can you make sure that this file is being read correctly and that its return is an actual JSON?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Try looking at a file called `.secrets-example` in your working directory. You could also try to print the results of the file, ex:

`console.log(fs.readFileSync('.secrets-example'))`

Is this off some tutorial? Maybe you can link that too

Comment: I solved the problem.
Thank you very much for your help